# Compare boolean WHERE predicates against Boolean Values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I am extending an in-house SQL Generator.

This Generator is designed in C# and I am adding the ability to build SQL Queries from Linq queries. The Linq Queries can have 'Constant' expressions (i.e. Expressions that become true/false/etc. prior to SQL generation).

To give an example, a linq query like:

```
var OuterProperty = *something*;
ParentObject.Where(
  element =>
    OuterProperty != null && element.Property == OuterProperty
)
```

can boil down to something like:

`SELECT Property FROM ParentObject WHERE true AND Property = OuterProperty`

This fails in SQL as I am using actual Boolean values in the where predicate.

My question is; 
Is it possible to use Constant values like booleans in this way?

---

To test this out, you can try the following snippet:

```
select 1 where IIF(true,1,0) = 1
```

This will give you the following error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '('.

Comment: I would expect your code to produce an error such as "unknown column `true`".

Comment: I used something like `1=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRUE and FALSE do not exist in SQL.

Instead use an expression which evaluates to true or false.

```
SELECT 'hello' WHERE (1 = 1);      // true:  selects 'hello'
SELECT 'world' WHERE (1 = 0);      // false: selects nothing
```

Since you are generating the SQL yourself, it's easy to optimize most of the booleans away:

```
WHERE true  AND x   ==>    WHERE x
WHERE false AND x   ==>    remove the whole select
WHERE false         ==>    remove the whole select
WHERE true  OR  x   ==>    no where clause
WHERE true          ==>    no where clause
WHERE false OR  x   ==>    WHERE x
```

Comment: I will try this suggestion now.